Latching Relay Modbus
Does anybody know if latching magnetic relays exist that can be controlled via Rs485 Modbus?
( Ive searched for weeks and cannot find one )
Ive tried a lot of relays but all lose their state after power outage but i need a relay that keeps state and is turned on and off by 2 different modbus commands

Hello and welcome.  You could of course use two modbus-controlled NO contacts to energise the set/reset coils of a bistable relay; or make a suitable modbus controlled one with almost any microcontroller + rs485 transceiver.  If you're after design advice for either of these, EESE is a good place.  It's not good for product recommendations for lots of reasons, but I'd expect this kind of item to exist commercially.

Does anybody know if latching magnetic relays exist that can be controlled via Rs485 Modbus? ... yes, the manufacturer, the seller, and anyone that purchases it

Something like a Sonoff WiFi relay might satisfy your requirements. Whilst not a latching relay, it can store the current state and restore this on power up. With firmware like Tasmota, it can probably be a Modbus slave device.
